# What is the optimum way to achieve large number of tables with large dataset

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

We have an API that is triggered during in app process.
This API is used for modification in around 20 tables in database.

This API call is triggered by users only once ,
Now we want to trigger this flow manually for 100000 users.
each call take around 10-15 seconds to complete database query
What will be the optimal strategy for doing this.

Comment: Make a function to do the same and put it on a regular interval on cron.

Comment: 20 is not a *large* number of tables, nor is 100000 a *large* number of records... if your API is taking 10-15 seconds to update 20 tables for a single user there's possibly an underlying performance issue you'll want to sort out first.

Comment: I would try to figure out if you can execute that action for every user at once. E.g. `update table set column = 1` for all users at once is much faster than 100.000 calls of `update table set column = 1 where id=xxx`. Especially if you don't have indexes that fit your query and thus operate on the full table (which, like cd001 already said, a 15 second query might imply), that method would be about 100.000 times faster. It will of course depend on the (unknown) process and (unknown) code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is serval solution, hope it will help.

1) You can use NGINX. It has better load balancing.It gives better concurrency. You can have look here https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-vs-apache-our-view/ .

2) You can deamonize your whole process. Just log your all api calls in your database. Write one Deamon who continuously read from DB whether any new entry is come. As soon as entry will come, It will perform all operation for that particular records.

3) You can use child process forking also for your Deamon. You can make mulitple child process of your Deamon.

I guess with this you can handle more number of API calls.

Comment: Ashish we already using nginx, and tried cron for same purpose but it start getting slow after some time.

Comment: Hi Alok, it&#39;s great if you using nginx. Make your process deamonize and makes multiple process. It will help you to handles multiple API call. You can also handles the number of process you want to run parallely, you can change accordingly number of API calls you getting. So to improve speed, you can log your API hits in memory by using redis or something else.